# Page to download a file requires processing in webclient

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to use a java servlet in a 3rd party tool's web interface (CA service desk) to invoke it's download file functionality using a webclient in vb.net. The trouble is the text stream from response is markup and not the acutual text file stream.

It's like the page is redirecting to another page which actually presents the file for downloading. I have no idea what the redirected page URL is.

Is there a way I can process this redirected page in order to get at the download using a system.net.webclient?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried listening with an HTTP debugging proxy when using the servlet in a normal situation, to identify exactly what parameters are being passed? It's possible that the servlet page expects certain parameters (such as the HTTP REFERER), and displays a piece of HTML if they were not provided.

Comment: so correct me, but it *sounds* like you're not following a prescribed/supported API route, then...?

Comment: There is a web service API, but it has no functionality to retrive a file from a record. It only has the ability to add or remove an attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Turn on logging](http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2007/08/enable-internal-systemnet-logging.html) for System.Net. You'll be able to see the full HTTP headers that are being sent and received. I'd recommend doing this from a desktop application and once you figure out the magic sequence then porting it to a web application.